# Method called twice in same moment

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I'm working on a windows forms application and fighting with a very harsh error. The application is supposed to run on a local machine and handle requests form a server applicaton. The client application looks like this:

```
public Reader mr_obj;

public Form1()
{
    mr_obj = new MyReader.Reader(7137);
    mr_obj.UserEvent += new ReaderEvent(UserEvent);
}

private void UserEvent(UserEvent e, long threadID)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   SafeSomethingToDB();
}
```

The Reader() object is connecting the client application to the server application. So after this, the server application is able to trigger the UserEvent() method in the client application. Ther problem is now, that the client application, which handles the UserEvents, crashes if the UserEvent() method gets triggered twice within one second.
(Its actually not crashing just hanging untill you kill the task, a try catch wont return an error)

What I've tried so far is to delegate the Thread.Sleep() and SafeSomethingToDB() to another thread. This doesnt work because the server application does not wait until the tread is finished. So the server application does not find the data in the DB because its not waiting 1 second... 
The same problem happens when I did that with background workers.

Is there a possibility to handle these two triggers, which come from the same server application, in sort of a parallell way at the same time?

Any suggestions very apreciated

EDIT: I think locking the method does not cause the application to process both triggers in the same time. To make this visible I'v tried this:

```
private void UserEventHandler(UserEvent e, long threadID)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Messagebox 1");
                MessageBox.Show("Messagebox 2");
            }
        }
```

When the first request triggers UserEvent() "MessageBox1" appeares. If you press OK, "MessageBox2" appeares. But  if the UserEvent gets triggered a second time while "Messagebox2" is still opened, "MessageBox1" does not appear. Instead of that the application start hanging. Shouldn "MessageBox1" appear again triggered by the second trigger of UserEvent() when the two triggers really ar bbeing processed at the same time? So the two triggers are not beeing preformed parallel or am I mistaking here?

Comment: Move `SaveSomethingToDB()` to the thread as well.

Comment: Edited, sorry wasn't eplained well. This was delegated too. But the server application isnt waiting for the thread to finish so it continues befor the entry in the DB is made.

Comment: Does the client crash if the `UserEvent()` method gets triggered twice within one second, or when the `SafeSomethingToDB()` gets called twice within one second (OR when the `SafeSomethingToDB()` method gets called again before the first call has exited)?

Comment: Yes, locking causes the calls to be handled one after another instead of at the same time. That's the whole point of locking.

Comment: @Roy Dictus I now logged every step into my eventlog. it seems to be crashing between the sleep() and the SafeSomethingToDB() method. So it probabely crashes if the event is triggered before SafeSomethingToDB() has finished working.

Comment: What does the sleep() call accomplish?  If you are not scheduling real-time events or trying to debug something, then sleep() is almost always a wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing why you do the `Sleep` or what exactly `SafeSomethingToDB` does and what causes your problems, try to synchronize the calls:

```
private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

private void UserEvent(UserEvent e, long threadID)
{
   lock(_lockObject)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       SafeSomethingToDB();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thaks for the reply. Unfortunately this does not work. Executing it twice still causes hanging. Have a look at my edit above :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple `lock` for synchronization will work for you, try this

```
public Reader mr_obj;
private static readonly object sync = new object();
public Form1()
{
    mr_obj = new MyReader.Reader(7137);
    mr_obj.UserEvent += new ReaderEvent(UserEvent);
}

private void UserEvent(UserEvent e, long threadID)
{
   lock(sync)
   {
      SafeSomethingToDB();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Locking doues unfortunately not work. Have a look at my edit above :)

Comment: The idea behind the lock is to make sure only one thread is working within the critical section, in your edit this is exactly what is expected. with what you have shown so far we can't help much, you have to determine the critical section and make sure you synchronize between the threads with semaphores or monitors(ie. lock) and make sure to take out any modal window from that section.

Answer (score 0):

As you write in the comments, if `SafeSomethingToDB()` is called a second time before the first call has finished, then it crashes. So in other words: `SafeSomethingToDB()` is not re-entrant.

What you can do is use a Mutex (which stands for mutual exclusion), which defines a "critical section" in your code, meaning a code that can have only one thread executing it at any one time.

For instance:

```
private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

public void SafeSomethingToDB()
{
    mutex.WaitOne(); // wait until it is safe to enter the critical section

    // Critical section begins here
    DoWorkAndStuff();

    mutex.ReleaseMutex(); // indicate the end of the critical section
}
```

For more about `System.Threading.Mutex`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx.